# Double Slit Experiment with Two Independent Sources

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, double-slit-experiment

Imagine a variation on the double slit experiment. I'll describe it in 2D using the $x-y$ plane. The $x$-axis is impenetrable other than the two slits, which are positioned at $(-1,0)$ and $(+1,0)$. Detectors will be positioned in the upper half plane, say along $y=10$ or something. Here's the twist: the negative $y$-axis is impenetrable as well. Two sources will be needed, say one at $(+1,-\infty)$ and the other at $(-1,\infty)$. These sources create plane waves impinging on the two slits.

The basic question: will one observe simple interference at the detectors?

For photons, I think the answer is obviously yes. (Maxwell's equations in free space are linear and there's no problem "superposing" or simply summing the contributions of each of the slits.)

But what if one uses electrons as the source? The wall separating the two sources clearly seems to preclude a single electron from taking both paths to the destination, as would be the case in the usual setup. That suggests you'll have to have more than one electron at a time involved to achieve interference. But electrons interact electromagnetically, and that interaction may wreck any interference pattern. In contrast, photons don't interact, so simple interference occurs there.

Alternatively, one might think that interference will still occur with single electrons, since there is no way to determine which source the electron came from.  Intuitively, I lean toward this answer being correct, but if it is, how would you understand the underlying Hilbert space and Hamiltonian of such a system? I don't think it can possibly be understood as a single electron system with a single wave function throughout space.

Or can it?

Comment: IMHO, the problem is more to know if your two sources $(+1,-\infty)$ and $(+1,-\infty)$ are coherent or not. If there is a coherence of the sources , there will be interferences. The nature of the particles should not play a special role.

Comment: @Trimok I think you should be able to assume coherence by modeling the electrons as plane waves moving in the $+y$ direction. (These are just momentum eigenfunctions.) As long as the electrons have the same momentum, the plane waves striking the slits should always be separated by constant phase. No? Am I misunderstanding something? In this case, I suspect you'll get interference as well, but I'm trying to understand how that can be. Should one model this system with a single wave function $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$? Even though the electrons on either side seem independent?

Comment: Coherence means a constant phase difference between the sources. So all depends on your experiment and  how you prepare your sources. For instance, if your $2$ sources are in fact secondary sources coming from one source (at infinity), there will be coherence.

Comment: @Trimok If they are plane waves with exactly the same momentum traveling in the same direction, then the phase difference between wave 1 at fixed point 1 and wave 2 at fixed point 2 is clearly independent of time. This is "coherent", I think. Theoretically, at least, I believe one should be able to achieve coherence while keeping the waves independent, in the sense that they are traveling on opposite sides of an impenetrable wall. And that's what confuses me: it seems the independence of sources suggests you'd need to model multiple particles at once. In which case, how could they interfere?